# Is it possible to play one video on top of another in Android?

Tags: android, video

I'm trying to figure out if Android can handle two video video players occupying the same screen space, preferably with the one on top having alpha channel regions that are transparent to the one behind.

I know how to implement this code wise, I'm curious if anyone knows if this is physically possible before I bother throwing coding time at it.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no, at least before Android 4.0. You can't have two `SurfaceViews` overlap.

Now, it is conceivable that this is possible with `TextureView` with Android 4.0, though I am far from confident of that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option :

*Player 1* : Stock MediaPlayer that renders on a SurfaceView

*Player 2* : Yet-another-player that can render on a GLSurfaceView or a Bitmap. This must be custom-built to decode frames and write on a GLSurfaceView's context or Native-bitmap via JNI.